# nullPointerException after Screen rotation

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout, screen-rotation

I get nullPointerException exception returned by object  `LinearLayout` after screen rotation although i am passing null in `onCreate()` super.onCreate(null); .
I know Activity must be destroyed and re-created beside i'm passing savedInstanceState = null that mean Activity should start after rotation as it start for first time, why i get this Exception after rotation  ?

**onCreate() snippet where `LinearLayout` object called historyText**

```
LinearLayout historyText ;  // this return exception if it used after rotation . 

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    historyText = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.historyLayoutText); 
    Log.e("HISTORYVISIBILITY", "VISIBILITY = "+historyText.getVisibility());
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    database = new Database(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    intent = extras.getInt("activity");
    p = new Progress();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.group, p)
                .commit();
    orientation = getRotation();
    switch (orientation){
        case "p" :
            addPlus();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): Process: developer.mohab.gymee, PID: 7768
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{developer.mohab.gymee/developer.mohab.gymee.Cardio.Cardio}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.LinearLayout.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.LinearLayout.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at developer.mohab.gymee.Cardio.Cardio.onCreate(Cardio.java:76)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
10-07 22:21:24.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     ... 11 more
10-07 22:21:24.633: E/SurfaceFlinger(319): rejecting buffer: bufWidth=1358, bufHeight=624, front.active.{w=193, h=193}
```

Comment: Don't call super.onCreate() with null argument or any arguments

Comment: if i did not Fragment add in onCreate() recreated again

Comment: Then do not add the fragment if it is already there. See if it is there, and use the existing instance rather than create a new one.

Comment: First, nice user name.... Second, on `at developer.mohab.gymee.Cardio.Cardio.onCreate(Cardio.java:76)` that is probably the Log line... this seems "correct" so far, but show us your onpause/onresume as well. Also, where are you running this? Check if onDestroy is collecting the variables, or if is still there.

Comment: @Bonatti thanx :) , this line mean that historyText.getVisibility() based on null object . because it does no re-initialized for some reason  and i did not call onDestroy ()

Comment: @Error I meant this: debug the device, and log the [activity lifecycle](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-activity). Most likely the device is not conserving the desired variables (and I would look on `onDestroy`, then `onStop`, finally `onPause` where its most likely that is happening.... Also, try to add as much information as possible on your question. Edit it, and writte: The Device (brand, OS version, Build Version), the IDE (Android Studio I am guessing), anything that may help us help you

Answer (score 10):

When you rotate the device the Activity and all the fragments on it are destroyed. to avoid this you should modify the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

this will prevent the Exception

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest file

```
<activity
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Hope this can be useful.